# Magento 2 datatypes. Need TIME (of day)

Tags: magento2, database, install-script, time

It appears that column data type `TIME` (*not `datetime`, just the time of day, for example `12:00`*) is not supported in `Magento 2`.

I need to store a time of day, how to work around this?
How should I go about it with the tools and datatypes that are available?

I thought about saving a normal but distinctive date (like `1970-01-01 12:00:00` which is distinctive enough not to be confusing to anyone browsing the data) and just extracting the time part from it in the `UI`, but it's horrid and makes me cringe inside.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Could you create a TIME format if it doesn't exist already?

Comment: @RobbieAverill attempted to a) override & extend the class `Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table` with my own additions and b) edit `Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table`  directly, but that didn't help (got all sort of errors on setup:upgrade ). Could you be more specific with what you mean by creating a TIME format?

Zend db should support time data type, but 
1. editing and adding 'TIME' column type in class Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table
2. calling Table->addColumn with 'TIME' type and any combination of options just causes

`[Zend_Db_Exception]
  Invalid column definition data`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using DATETIME initially

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('MYTABLE'))
        ->addColumn(
            'MYCOLUMN', 
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null,
           ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => true],
            'Comment about table'
        );
```

`

and then just using raw sql execution with

`$installer->run('ALTER TABLE MYTABLE MODIFY MYCOLUMN TIME');`

And that was it, problem solved.

Comment: It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magento ORM does not implement exotic date types. You have two options:

1. Rewrite every single DDL class in Magento 2.0 Framework and introduce a headache to maintain it with every new release of Magento 2.0 as it might break.
2. Use another available datatype, not necessarily a date related one, because it might introduce performance degradation. You can try to use INT that is a digit only representation of time. Then, for example, `10:11:43` will be represented as such value in integer column `101143`. And you still can do the same operations on MySQL level as with regular `TIME` time (`BETWEEN`, `<`, `>`, etc). There is no performance degradation in using int instead of time. (I don't recommend `VARCHAR` representation as it is slower to search over its index)

Answer (score 0):

If I had to be honest: do it 'The Magento Way™'. That's the way you're least likely to get headaches with forward compatibility. I know, I'd like to see a `TIME`-type as well, but if Magento only supports `DATETIME` (most likely due to abstraction of the datasource), use that instead, even if it makes you cringe.

Who knows... maybe one day Magento might decide that version 2.x is going to support a newer, faster database that doesn't support `TIME`. Having rewritten your DDL's (or altering your raw tables on the fly) might have some nasty side-effects then.